# Return list not typed

Tags: java

I have a java class which can return a list, may be list of two differents classes.

```
public List getMyList{

if ...
return List<Classe1>
else
return List<Classe2>

}
```

}

```
public interface IClasse {

}
class Classe1 implements IClasse{
...
}
class Classe2 implements IClasse{
...
}
```

I my Spring editor , if I try to code

```
public List<IClasse> getMyList {

}
```

there is a error, it want to cast Classe1 or Classe2

if I write just  public List getMyList no error ....

What the best way to resolve my problem,
Why this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: There is no cast here. What is the error?

Comment: `List getMyList(...)` returns a _raw_ type. Avoid it as the plague.

Comment: I suppose the problem is relative to Java _invariance_ on type arguments. _Invariance_ said that if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `List<A>` **is not** a subtype of `List<B>`.

Comment: ok riccardo but how to do so ?